# insert multiple records in java "No operations allowed after connection closed "

Tags: java

I have a function to insert data using JDBC but it works just for one record how can insert multiple records dynamicaly

```
public void insertInfo() throws Exception{
    try{
        int codeNat = getNat();

        String query = "INSERT INTO info (id,name,code_nat) VALUES (?,?,?)";

        stat = cnx.prepareStatement(query);
        stat.setString(1, txtId.getText());
        stat.setString(2, txtName.getText());
        stat.setInt(3, codeNat);

        stat.execute();
        Update_table();

    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
    }
    finally{
        try{
            stat.close();
            cnx.close();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

the exception i had "No operations allowed after connection closed."

Comment: Post your code please, including the full error and stack trace.

Comment: your resources `stat,cnx` are closed after first insert.

Comment: but i have to close it no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing your connection (cnx) in the finally of your method. This will close the connection the first time you insert (whether it fails or passes) and then the connection will still be closed the next time you come along to insert. You can try moving the connection opening into this method if you like, but connection can be expensive to open/close, perhaps move the closing/opening outside this method. It's really hard to say until we see more of the code you're working on.

Comment: some one told me to add a batch but i didn't know what is it, i've removed cnx.close() it works , thank you

Comment: careful though, you don't want to leave database connections open. You need to close that connection once you're done inserting data